# How to change Button control's text inside Repeater control and catch its click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am trying to create buttons using asp:repeater

This is what I have:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptQuery" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text='<%this.GetDataItem().ToString() %>' 
            OnClick="Unnamed_Click" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I have no idea how to change the button text to reflect the value obtained from rptQUery's source ( a list of strings) and the onclick event to refer to this particular button.

Any advice please?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: BTW, Google "ASP.NET databinding" and you may find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to maniupluate the binding and appearance of Button control.

Then use [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.command(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the Button control to capture the posted data.

### ASPX

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptQuery" runat="server"
    OnItemDataBound="rptQuery_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" OnCommand="Button1_Command" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

### Code Behind

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var customers = new List<Customer>
        {
            new Customer {Id = 1, Name = "Jon"},
            new Customer {Id = 2, Name = "Eric"}
        };

        rptQuery.DataSource = customers;
        rptQuery.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void rptQuery_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var customer = e.Item.DataItem as Customer;
        var button = e.Item.FindControl("Button1") as Button;

        button.CommandName = customer.Id.ToString();
        button.Text = customer.Name;
    }
}

protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandName);
    // Do something with id
}
```

Comment: var customer = e.Item.DataItem as Customer; customer is coming null. so unable to bind

Comment: @Mysterio11 It might be that your Grid's **DataSource** is not **List<Customer>**. This question has been answered. If you want me to look at your code, please create a new question in SO and paste the link here?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a ItemDataBinding event and handling this in code like so:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptQuery" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptQuery_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button id="btnUnnamed" runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed_Click" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then your method would look something like this.

```
protected void rptQuery_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var data = e.Item.DataItem as string;

        var btnUnnamed = e.Item.FindControl("btnUnnamed") as Button;
        if (btnUnnamed != null)
        {
            btnUnnamed.Text = data;
        }
    }
}
```